# value vs. pointer: is `*x=y` equivalent to `x=&y`?

Tags: go

say `y := []int`

say `x := *[]int`

Question 1: **is `*x=y` equivalent to `x=&y`?**

I found that, when y is updated, say `y=y[1:]`, `*x=y` gave me correct updated `y`, whereas `x=&y` still gave me the old `y`.

Question 2: **Why it is like this?**

Comment: What other programming languages have you used? Pointers can be confusing, but the best ways to explain them depends on what you already know.

Comment: Your experimentation shows that they're different, so why are you asking if they're the same?

Comment: @filmzy most of time I got the same results but I just noticed the difference so that's why I asked. I found your comment is particularly not encouraging

Comment: @ torek  I'm using python and js mostly.

Answer (score 6):

No, they're not the same, and they do what they say. `*x = y` modifies `*x` by assigning `y` to it (there are two different `[]int`, one at `*x` and one at `y`). `x = &y` modifies `x` by assigning `&y` to it (`x` points to the same `[]int` named by `y`).